# Sending special characters (i.e. caron) through xmlhttp.responseText using json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to grab data with a special character (caron) from a database and send it through xmlhttp.responseText using json_encode to populate textboxes. The specific textbox associated with the data containing the special character (caron) is displaying nothing. The other textboxes are displaying correct data. I tried using the Javascript function encodeURIComponent, but only null showed in the textbox. Any help would be appreciated.

Main page code:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         document.getElementById("textbox").value=a.first;
         document.getElementById("textbox2").value=a.second;
         document.getElementById("textbox3").value=a.third;
         document.getElementById("textbox4").value=a.fourth;
         document.getElementById("textbox5").value=a.fifth;
         document.getElementById("textbox6").value=a.sixth;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

loadTextBox.php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

---Placeholder for correct DB login info---

$result = $mysql->query(---Placeholder for correct SQL query---);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult[] = $row->colun_one;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
$textboxValue3 = $queryResult[2];
$textboxValue4 = $queryResult[3];
$textboxValue5 = $queryResult[4];
$textboxValue6 = $queryResult[5];
echo    
json_encode(array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>$textboxValue2,
'third'=>$textboxValue3,'fourth'=>$textboxValue4,'fifth'=>$textboxValue5,
'sixth'=>$textboxValue6));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding in the line $mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); inside loadTextBox.php after connecting to the DB and before the SQL query fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Encode them using UTF-8 before sending them.

`utf8_encode($variable);`

or try `array_map();` to encode the array;

```
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
$textboxValue3 = $queryResult[2];
$textboxValue4 = $queryResult[3];
$textboxValue5 = $queryResult[4];
$textboxValue6 = $queryResult[5];
$arrayToEncode = array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>$textboxValue2,
'third'=>$textboxValue3,'fourth'=>$textboxValue4,'fifth'=>$textboxValue5,
'sixth'=>$textboxValue6);
$encodedArray = array_map('utf8_encode', $arrayToEncode);
echo json_encode($encodedArray);
```

you may also need to set your `xmlhttp.request` to `utf-8` as well

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

You may need to try one or the other or even both. You also want to confirm your DB is able to store special characters, if the DB is not storing the special chars then there is no way your application will be able to get them to encode them.

Comment: array_map makes it so that every letter of the word that has the caron in it gets displayed (same thing encodeURIComponent function does), but the letter that has the caron above it still does not get displayed. Using the setRequestHeader causes nothing to be displayed. I can see the caron in my DB, so I'm assuming the DB is able to sore the special character.

Comment: @programm3r what is your database encoding?

Comment: I'm using Cpanel. MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci. MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8). The collation listed for the table in the DB is latin1_swedish_ci. When I browse the table in Cpanel through phpMyAdmin it shows the caron above the letter.

Comment: @programm3r try removing the `array_map` call I did. I added that thinking your collation was not utf-8. Also if you access the php page manually is the correct characters shown?

Comment: When I access the php page manually the word null is in the place where the word with the caron should be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16611/discussion-between-bot-and-programm3r)

Comment: utf8_encode is not needed but the line $mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); is needed inside loadTextBox.php after connecting to the DB and before the SQL query